# How to display text on hover without moving content on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I am trying to display some content when the mouse hovers over a photo. However, I am having a hard time doing this without moving the rest of the content on the page (below).

How would I implement a solution to display the content right under the top 3 images without using `margin-top: -22%`?

[Here is a link to the site](http://aswanson.net/ConnectWithTrainingHomePage/MyHomePage.html)

```
.eCommerce{
    margin-left: 7%;
}

.photo1-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo1:hover .photo1-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -22%;
    margin-left: 13%;
}

.photo2-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo2:hover .photo2-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -22%;
    margin-left: 44%;
}

.photo3-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo3:hover .photo3-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -22%;
    margin-left: 75%;
}

.photo4-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo4:hover .photo4-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-left: 13%;
}

.photo5-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo5:hover .photo5-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-left: 44%;
}

.photo6-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo6:hover .photo6-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-left: 75%;
}

.enterprise{
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: u can try bootsrap popover for this. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael_B is correct about `display: none`. The element is not in the flow of your DOM until it becomes displayed. As it sounds like you've discovered, different browsers handle the `visibility` [property differently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

If what you are trying to do is merely display the text under the photos on hover without having the surrounding content "bounce", a really easy trick is to put the text in the flow of the document wherever you want it to be displayed and style it with `color: transparent`.

So, without being able to see your HTML and based solely on your provided code, a possible solution would look like this:

```
.photo1-content{
    color: transparent;
}

.photo1:hover .photo1-content{
    color: black;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I adjusted margins to counteract the images getting pulled up, I will close the question.